# how to use Like statement to get encrypted value from a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, encryption, sql-like

how to use like statement in encrypted column in mysql

i need to get user id from a table where username is like some value(user given input). but my username column is locally encrypted and stored in DB.
Now, how to get the decrypt value from DB for using like statement.
i am using Like statement in search method to get the values from the table that matches it, but values are encrypted in table.

For example:
vi - 68726rgur4746r279267(encrypted type first name in db).

when i type vi in the search box everything that starts with word vi should be taken from the db.

Comment: You can't search on an encrypted column without first decrypting it.

Comment: which encrypt method do you use?

Comment: i am using AES encrypt method for encryption and decryption.

Comment: Why are you encrypting usernames?

Comment: to get the matching columns. i have to first decrypt the usernames from table and compare them.

Comment: But why are the usernames encrypted in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can't search on an encrypted column without first decrypting it.

```
Select * From table
WHERE AES_DECRYPT(col_name,key_str) LIKE '%something%'
```

Comment: can u show me any links or examples, i tried with what u explained above but it didn't work for me.

Comment: try this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613289/mysql-select-where-like-with-aes-encrypt] @Vicky

Comment: tried its not working Select USER_ID,AES_DECRYPT(USER_FIRST_NAME, "aes.key") as username From user

Comment: import play.api.libs.Crypto._                                                                       val encrypted_username = encryptAES(user_first_name, aesKey.get) we are encrypting the username through coding not directly using sql query.